# Why can't we close and migrate Music Stack Exchange questions to anywhere other than the Music Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When clicking on "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" in a question's "close" menu on Music Stack Exchange, the only Stack Exchange offered as an option is music.meta.stackexchange.com. Despite other Stack Exchange websites being offered as suggestions in https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic (a link accessed by clicking on the "music.meta.stackexchange.com" link provided by the "close" menu), including [Music Fans](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/), [Law.SE](http://law.stackexchange.com/), and [SoftwareRecs.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), none of them are available as options to close and migrate a Music Stack Exchange question to.

Why is this the case? Are there ways to allow Music Stack Exchange questions to be closed and migrated to the above Stack Exchanges the same way they can be closed and migrated to Music Meta Stack Exchange? I've personally wanted the ability to close and migrate so many song identification questions on Music Stack Exchange to Music Fans Stack Exchange myself....

Comment: Note that Law.SE is no longer in beta, but the other points of the duplicate question about vetting the migration are still important.

Answer (score 5):

Generally when sites are in beta they only allow migration to the meta site. If you want something moved elsewhere you are best flagging for a mod, as we can migrate anywhere.

I will see if we can have music fans added as a target site, because it is our main extralegal migration destination.